# Simplest octave up (pitch shifter) circuit

Tags: audio, sound

What is simplest circuit to pitch instrument (bass) one (or two) octave(s) up ?
I am asking for this because there are no electronic shops where i live, and getting parts, especially chips is pretty hard, you can not even get 555 timer chip over here, all i have at hand is PC power supply and random board, most probably volume control, from soviet TV, i heard that diode bridge rectifier can double the frequency because output from guitar is AC and when it is converted to pulsing DC, frequency of this pulsing DC will be 2x higher, is this true ?
tl;dr i want to make simple octave up stompbox for bass guitar, quality is non issue

Comment: Simple rectifying will distort the sound. You really want a sample-and-duplicate circuit for this (since up one octave is double the frequency).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams distortion is not issue, but will it shift an octave up ?

Comment: Have you experimented to see what it does?

Comment: A bridge rectifier will certainly generate a lot of overtones, but only if the signal level exceeds two forward diode drops (at least +/-1.5 V peaks). The raw signal from a guitar pickup would be several orders of magnitude too small, so you'll have to use a preamp of some sort. Calling this a "pitch shifter" is a bit of a stretch, though.

Comment: The modern world will suggest the use of a DSP or at least software.  A fast PC with a sound card may be able to do two Fast Fourier Transforms on the fly, worth looking into.

Comment: @KalleMP the problem is not the speed of the PC (PCs have been able to do this kind of thing fast enough in real time since the early nineties), but mainly: to do an FFT is not enough; the FFT must have enough resolution to tell single tones apart. High resolution means "many FFT points"; many FFT points imply a) high latency and b) the timbre (ie. tonal composition) varies over time after "plucking" a string, but your FFT is "long" compared to that–so either you don't get the resolution necessary to perfectly identify tones and double their frequency, or you "swallow temporal characteristics"

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have a vague idea of the limitations, this is why I did not imply a ready solution but still perhaps adequate for the OP, he did imply low quality needs.  Just doing an AGC and rectification in software may be all he needs. with perhaps an envelope shaper after from the AGC control signal, I expect this has been done in the analogue domain in the past but debugging in code should be easier for a one off.

Comment: and @MarcusMüller, they've been doing this (with DSPs) even before the 90s.  Eventide H3000 used the [TMS32010](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320c15.pdf) and comes from the 80s.  and they didn't do it with any FFT.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson the more you know :) Are you aware that you're becoming my go-to ressource on 90s (and now, pre-nineties) DSP hardware? (by the way, how? All I can think of is "this screams for spectral analysis", but FFT would be the "easiest" specest that I can think of. Or you'd just decimate the input signal by two after proper filtering, and play the same segment twice, possibly overlapping with other segments)

Comment: if you're doing pitch shifting with the FFT, even with an infinitely fast computer, you have the delay time of an FFT buffer, which could be 50 or 100 ms.  way too long for live use.  these pitch shifters work in the time domain using a pitch detector (so you know how long a period is) and then splicing and resampling.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "simple" circuit that can do that. Essentially, your circuit would have to mimic autotune – which is a complex signal processing approach.

Think of it like this:

Shifting a single tone by an octave is in fact really just doubling its frequency.

That's easy to do – you just multiply the tone with itself.

What happens when you multiply a \$\cos (2\pi f_1 t)\$ with  \$\cos (2\pi f_2 t)\$ is that you get *mixing*, ie. you get two resulting tones:

\$\cos (2\pi f_1 t) \cdot \cos (2\pi f_2 t) =  \frac12\Big(\cos \big(2\pi (f_1+f_2) t\big)+\cos \big(2\pi (f_1-f_2) t\big)\Big)\$

one at the sum frequency, one at the difference frequency. So if we set \$f_1=f_2\$, we get

$$\begin{align}
\cos \big(2\pi f_1 t\big)\cdot\cos \big(2\pi f_1 t\big)&=\cos^2 \big(2\pi f_1 t\big)\\
&= \frac12\Big(\cos \big(2\pi (f_1+f_1) t\big)+\cos \big(2\pi (f_1-f_1) t\big)\Big)\\
&= \frac12\Big(\cos \big(2\pi 2f_1 t\big)+\cos \big(2\pi 0 t\big)\Big)\\
&= \frac12\Big(\cos \big(2\pi 2f_1 t\big)+\cos 0\Big)\\
&= \frac12\cos \big(2\pi 2f_1 t\big)+\frac12
\end{align}
$$

which means you get a DC offset, plus the tone shifted by an octave. Woohoo! That multiplier can be readily bought (e.g. as SA612).

Now, luckily, bass strings don't make single tones – they have timbre, which means they typically produce overtones. Let's, for the sake of simplicity, just assume there was a single overtone, at \$f_2=2f_1\$.

So that leads to  our bass sound being

$$\begin{align}
s(t) &= \cos (2\pi f_1 t) + \cos (2\pi f_2 t)\\
&= \cos (2\pi f_1 t) + \cos (2\pi 2f_1 t)\text{ .}
\end{align}$$

inherently, when we now mix the sound with itself, we get
$$\begin{align}
s^2(t)
&= \Big(\cos (2\pi f_1 t) + \cos (2\pi f_2 t)\Big)^2\\
&\quad\quad\text{ Notice: $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$}\\
&= \underbrace{\cos^2 (2\pi f_1 t)}_{\frac12 + \frac12\cos(2\pi 2f_1)} + 2 \underbrace{\cos (2\pi f_1 t)\cos (2\pi f_2 t)}_\text{interesting part}+ \underbrace{\cos^2 (2\pi f_2 t)}_{\frac12 + \frac12\cos(2\pi 2\cdot f_2)}\\
&= 1 + \frac12\cos(2\pi 2f_1 t) +\frac12\cos(2\pi 2f_2 t) + \underbrace{2\cdot \frac12\Big(\cos\big(2\pi (f_1+f_2)t\big)+\cos\big(2\pi(f_1-f_2)t\big)\Big)}_\text{interesting part}\\
&= 1 
\\&\quad+ \frac12\cos(2\pi 2f_1 t) 
\\&\quad+\frac12\cos(2\pi 2f_2 t) 
\\&\quad+ \cos\big(2\pi (f_1+f_2)t\big)
\\&\quad+\cos\big(2\pi(f_1-f_2)t\big) \\
&\text{with $f_2 = 2f_1$:}\\
&= 1 + \underbrace{\frac12\cos(2\pi 2f_1 t)}_\text{base tone + octave} 
+\underbrace{\frac12\cos(2\pi 4f_1 t)}_\text{overtone + octave}
+ \underbrace{\cos\big(2\pi (3f_1)t\big)}_\text{3$\times$ base tone?!} +\underbrace{\cos\big(2\pi(-f_1)t\big)}_\text{base tone}
\end{align}$$

So when mixing a signal that is a sum of multiple tones (such as *any* note played by an instrument), you will always get these so-called *intermodulations*. Here, you get an unexpected original tone, and a tone at three times the base frequency, where you should get none at all! Also, these "undesired" tones are twice as strong as the tones you were actually hoping for.

There's no chance of filtering out these tones, since they happen in between desired tones.

Plus: usually, there's not only two tones that  your bass string emits, but it's a mixture of a couple dozen tones, all varying in intensity over time, and one prominent feature of bass is that the strings continue to resonate while you're already exciting the next string – so you can easily have dozens of tones, intermodulating, giving you a whole world of new tones.

In fact, that's part of the math behind simple, non-clipping bass effects: put the bass signal \$s(t)\$ through a diode or transistor with *nonlinear* behaviour. *Nonlinear* especially meaning you square (and cube, and take to the power of 4, 5, 6...) the signal, adding intermodulation.

So much signal theory for a musician today :) Well, the takeaway is that with simple circuits that don't "understand" (ie. do a mathematical analysis based on a signal model) the instrument, you *cannot* build an even "bad" octave shifter, because your shifting is bound to be weaker than the undesired intermodulations.

Comment: Gotta give a +1 for all the maths.  Agree also that filtered/selected second harmonics may already be the desired result.

Comment: If the instrument will only be playing in a range of roughly two octaves, it may be practical to pass it through a low-pass filter and a automatic-gain-control stage, and then self-multiply the output of that.  Doing so won't totally eliminate odd harmonics, but should reduce their level to the point that the desired harmonics dominate and the odd harmonics simply sound like a note played in its original octave.

Comment: The Electroharmonix Micro Synthesizer generates it's octave up voice just by low-pass filtering the signal at 700Hz, then doing rectification of the signal with an ideal diode opamp circuit. Crude, but for single notes it works pretty good.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck can you elaborate more ? where can i find schemes ?

Comment: @SEQUENCE666 there are several guitar octave up and octave down effects units [here](http://www.generalguitargadgets.com/effects-projects/octave/). Most are simple transistor designs using the equivalent of full-wave rectification to achieve the frequency doubling.